# What's the best way to interact with excel using c# 4.0?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

Right now I'm researching so I'm not sure what the requirements are. Just for now I need to import serialize and deserialize data to/from excel.
I don't want to use 3º parties libraries, even if they are open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyFile.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");

OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", con);
```

I use the Type OleDbConnection to create a connection to the Excel file. Then we can query the sheets like a regular database.

Give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.